# "Call off" somebody from his post?

Tags: expressions, phrase-requests, vocabulary

I am looking for a term that I could use to say that the new Minister of Health removed the present holder of the given post from his position. My first idea was *call off*, but then I looked up the meaning and learnt that one can *call off* dogs, not a person from his job.

Comment: Dismiss, Discharge

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps we could say:

The Minister asked X to **step down**.

The Minister **removed** X from the post of ... .

X was asked to step down (by the Minister).  (in the passive form)

Comment: It's true the Minister would probably say *he asked X to step down*. But the press would normally report it as *he **sacked** X*.